# Ao selecionar determinado valor no combobox, inserir valores em outro

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu gostaria de inserir valores no combobox 2 dependendo da escolha no combobox 2.

Tenho este código mas não funciona ou seja não insere os valores pretendidos no combobox 2.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(new Item("Blue", 1));
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente seu código está certo, creio que seja o problema no `if`

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(new Item("Blue", 1));
}
```

Utilizando para comparar no `if` é `==`.

E para adicionar no combobox, é desta forma:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Tokyo");
```

Dê uma olhada neste [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-items-in-combobox-in-c-sharp/), mude a forma de adicionar também.

Faça o teste, e me informe.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como saber qual é o erro que você está cometendo. A pergunta não mostra detalhes suficientes para isso.

Portanto, vou te mostrar um exemplo mínimo e completo funcionando.

No `Load` do Form preenchi o primeiro combobox e defini os `DisplayMember` e `ValueMember`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = new[]
    {
        new { Id = 1, Nome = "Item 0" },
        new { Id = 1, Nome = "Item 1" }
    }.ToArray();

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Nome";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

O `SelectedIndexChanged` fica praticamente igual, apenas corrigi o erro de sintaxe que tem na pergunta (são dois sinais de igual, não um) e tirei aquela classe `Item` porque não sei como foi definida.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(new { Id = 1, Nome = "Item 2" });
    }
}
```

Veja um GIF do funcionamento

[image]

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @CesarGoulart ótimo. Pra constar: você pode marcar a resposta como correta usando o V do lado esquerdo dela